std::is_same_v weirdly return false when true is expected using CRT pattern
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename,unsigned,typename...>typename interface,typename T,unsigned ChannelN, typename...Args>
struct base : public interface<T,ChannelN,Args...>{
    public:
    using Scalar = T;
};

template<typename T, unsigned ChannelN,typename... ColourT>
struct I{
    
};

template <typename T,unsigned ChannelN>
struct Scalar : public base<I,T,ChannelN>
{
     using DoubleT = double;
     using Name= Scalar;
     using base<I, T, ChannelN>::base;
};

int main()
{
   std::cout<<std::is_same_v<typename Scalar<int,1>::Scalar,int>;
  return 0;
}

I have a large code structured similar to the above , the code return false when i expected it to be true, i think there is a conflict betweenusing Name = Scalar in struct Scalar and using Scalar = T in struct base. How do I solve this without changing using Scalar=T?

You're going to have to share the (minimised version!) of the code which is going wrong. Pasting code which is correct isn't going to help anyone.

@MikeVine actually this is already the minimised version, i just didn't include the operators , member functions and constructor..

Clang gives warning

Found the error, there is a conflict between Name= Scalar and  Scalar = T

The problem is that typename Scalar<int,1>::Scalar refers to the ctor. Instead you want to use the alias Name as shown below. Clang even gives warning for the same.

How do I solve this without changing using Scalar=T?

By changing using Name = Scalar to
using Name= typename base<I,T,ChannelN>::Scalar; //changed this

Then when when using std::is_same_v, use the above modified Name as shown below:
//------------------------------------------------vvvv------>use Name instead of Scalar
std::cout<<std::is_same_v<typename Scalar<int,1>::Name,int>;

Working demo
Now the output of the program is what you want 1.

I need std::cout<<std::is_same_v<typename Scalar<int,1>::Scalar,int>;  to return true without changing using Name and Using Scalar. basically Name refers to the struct, Base::Scalar is the data type such as double, int. It just happened that i have a struct which is called Scalar as well... which i guess ends up with a conflict Name= Scalar, Scalar = double .

std::cout<<std::is_same_v<typename Scalar<int,1>::base::Scalar,int>; fixed the issue

@Dong Yeah adding base:: is another alternative.
